# Comprobar si todos los elementos de una matriz son impares

Tags: java, matrices

**Ejercicio: Desarrolla un método que reciba una matriz de enteros y nos devuelva true si todos los
elementos son impares y false en caso contrario**

-Matriz que envío:

```
boolean comprobar;
int [][] matriz={{1,1,1,1}, 
                 {4,1,3,1},
                 {1,1,1,1}};
comprobar=ej.ejercicio32(matriz);
        System.out.println("El resultado es: "+comprobar);
}
    }
```

-Método:

```
public boolean ejercicio32 (int[][] matriz){
    boolean comprobar=true;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            if(matriz[i][j]%2!=0){
                return comprobar;
            } 
            
        }
        
    }
    return comprobar=false;
}
}
```

**El problema es que aún teniendo el 4 en la matriz, me devuelve true (Supongo que es porque el bucle for sigue corriendo, pero entonces como sería? Un saludo!**

Answer (score 6):

Dos observaciones:

1. En el segundo `for` estas recorriendo las columnas siempre de la primera fila, no de todas las filas.
2. Estas haciendo el condicional mal, puesto que lo que  deberías evaluar es si existe algún numero par dentro de la matriz, en caso de ser verdadero hacer el `return` en `false`, de lo contrario seguir recorriendo la matriz y si no encuentra ninguno sale de los ciclos `for` y hace el respectivo `return` en `true`.

Ejemplo:

```
public boolean ejercicio32 (int[][] matriz){
    //boolean comprobar=true; Esta variable no es necesaria declararla
  
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) { //corregir matriz[0].length por matriz[i].length
            if(matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0){ //evalua si el numero es par
                return false; //corta el flujo de ejecucion y devuelve false
            } 
            
        }
        
    }
    return true; // si no encuentra numeros pares devuelve true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El operador `%` lo que hace es calcular el resto de la división, al dividir `4` por `2` no te queda nada y por eso es true porque el resto da `0`.

En tu caso el resto de dividir `4` entre `2` es `0` y por eso es true.

```
4%2 == 0 //el resto de dividir 4 por 2 cual es? 0 y, ¿0 es igual a 0?, afirmativo
```

El numero de la izquierda es el numero que quieres dividir, el de la derecha la cantidad por la que quieres dividir `4`. el resultado de la operación es cuanto queda sobrando de esa división.

Comment: Si por eso he puesto:if(matriz[i][j]%2!=0){
                return comprobar; Es decir si es resultado es diferente a 0 es true y si no es false

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean ejercicio32 (int[][] matriz){
    boolean esPar = true;
    boolean esImpar = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            if(matriz[i][j]%2 == 0){
                esImpar= false;
            } else {
                esPar = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(esPar && !esImpar) return true;
    else if(!esPar && esImpar) return false;
}
```

De esa forma te dará `true` si es **TODA** la matriz impar y `false` si **TODA** la matriz es par. Quedaría una condicional, error o bandera para el caso de que la matriz contenga valores par e impar.

Comment: oara que hacer el recorrido de todo el arreglo si ya con un solo elemento par rompe la condicion

Comment: Depende su propósito, si quiere verificar solo que tenga impares o si quiere verificar que toda la matriz sea par o impar. Sí es el segundo caso, claro que en cuanto detecte un número par puede roper el ciclo.